# how to compare continuous variables with their means by row

Tags: r

I need to compare four continuous variables with their means in r by rows, if three of them more than means, the result in fifth column should be Yes, otherwise No.

```
library(dplyr)
dd <- select_if(iris, is.numeric)
means <- apply(dd, 2, mean)
dd[1,] > means
```

if I have 3 TRUE in row the result in 5 var - important_cases will Yes, if not No, and I must do in for all rows.

Comment: Please share your data with `dput` and post the output.

Comment: @JimChen, the data is `iris[,1:4]` (though the rest of the question -- and output -- is unclear).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure you want this or not but I hope this helps:

```
data(iris)
df <- iris[, 1:4]
cm = colMeans(df)
df[,5] = apply(df, 1, function(x){
    compares = x> cm
        if(sum(compares) == 3){
            return ("YES")
        }else{
            return ("No")
            }
})
```

I you want 3 or more than of variables be more than their means to output become "YES", use `>=` instead of '==' in 6'rd line,

Comment: Your welcome, Anyway read @r2evans answer too, it's more clean. happy coding.

Answer (score 1):

```
df <- iris[,1:4]
colMeans(df)
# Sepal.Length  Sepal.Width Petal.Length  Petal.Width 
#     5.843333     3.057333     3.758000     1.199333 
df$Compare <- ifelse(rowSums(df > colMeans(df)) > 3, "Yes", "No")
tail(df)
#     Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Compare
# 145          6.7         3.3          5.7         2.5      No
# 146          6.7         3.0          5.2         2.3     Yes
# 147          6.3         2.5          5.0         1.9      No
# 148          6.5         3.0          5.2         2.0      No
# 149          6.2         3.4          5.4         2.3      No
# 150          5.9         3.0          5.1         1.8     Yes
```

Comment: Thank You very Much!!! It works perfect!!! I'm novice in r and till now it not so easy for me. Thank's a lot for your help!